File not found for out-of-line `mod` via `include!`
My file structure looks like this (yes this is for advent of code):
days.rs
days/
  day01.rs
  day02.rs
  ...

I generate a days.in file in build.rs which looks something like this:
pub mod day01;
pub mod day02;
...

I then include! this file in days.rs:
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/days.in"));

When I then cargo run or cargo build, I get this error repeated for each day:
error[E0583]: file not found for module `day01`                                                                                       
 --> D:\Projects\advent-of-code-2024\target\debug\build\advent-of-code-2024-59c0dcca155b0f0e\out\days.in:1:1
  |
1 | pub mod day01;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: to create the module `day01`, create file "D:\Projects\advent-of-code-2024\target\debug\build\advent-of-code-2024-59c0dcca155b0f0e\out\day01.rs" or "D:\Projects\advent-of-code-2024\target\debug\build\advent-of-code-2024-59c0dcca155b0f0e\out\day01\mod.rs"      
  = note: if there is a `mod day01` elsewhere in the crate already, import it with `use crate::...` instead

I notice that the error is located in days.in, while I would expect it to be in days.rs.
I suspect this is where I'm perhaps misunderstanding something. Does include! not just directly "copy-and-paste" the contents of the target file in place of the macro?

When I manually include the file, by just copying the contents of days.in and replacing the include! with it, it works perfectly fine!

Please post your build.rs so we can reproduce your whole setup

Your assumption simply is wrong, include! does not "copy-and-paste" anything it:

Parses a file as an expression or an item according to the context.

Parsing a file involves declaring modules so they still remain relative to the included file, not the including one.

Aha, I see now, thanks! I'll try using the #[path = "..."] attribute on the mods to point to the actual files. And otherwise just manually update the mods.

For future viewers with a similar question, this is what my build.rs ended up looking like. The important part is to add #[path = "<absolute path to the mod file>"] for each mod. (But really I'll probably just manually attach the files, since that seems to give better IDE support.)
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufWriter;
use std::io::Write;
use std::path::Path;
use std::{env, fs};

fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/days");

    // Collect days `(mod name, mod path)`
    let mut days = vec![];
    for entry in fs::read_dir("src/days").unwrap() {
        let entry = entry.unwrap();
        let day_name = entry
            .path()
            .file_stem()
            .unwrap()
            .to_str()
            .unwrap()
            .to_string();
        let day_path = entry
            .path()
            .to_str()
            .unwrap()
            .to_string()
            .replace('\\', "\\\\");

        // Skip day template
        if day_name == "dayN" {
            continue;
        }

        days.push((day_name, day_path));
    }

    let out_dir = env::var_os("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
    let out_days_path = Path::new(&out_dir).join("days.in");
    let out_days_file = File::create(out_days_path).unwrap();
    let mut out_days_writer = BufWriter::new(out_days_file);

    // Attach mods, with absolute path specified to the actual mod file
    for (day_name, day_path) in &days {
        writeln!(out_days_writer, "#[path = \"{}\"]", day_path).unwrap();
        writeln!(out_days_writer, "pub mod {};", day_name).unwrap();
    }

    // Implement wrapper functions
    writeln!(out_days_writer, "impl_days! {{").unwrap();
    for (day_name, _) in &days {
        writeln!(out_days_writer, "    {},", day_name).unwrap();
    }
    writeln!(out_days_writer, "}}").unwrap();

    out_days_writer.flush().unwrap();
}


You could also put your code in a proc-macro instead of emitting code in build.rs that way your mod statements can be placed in the correct file.
